# Questions without any answer from an user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `questions` table, a `user` table and an `answers` table with `user_id` and `question_id` as foreign keys.

I tried:

```
select questions.title from questions
full outer join answers on answers.question_id = questions.id
where answers.user_id = 1
group by questions.id
having count(answers.id) = 0
```

But the issue is that when questions.id is null it groups by null

Ideally the query should be doable with ActiveRecord (Ruby on Rails).

Comment: Why not express this in ActiveRecord terms instead of SQL?

Comment: `when questions.id is null it groups by null` - Why is your primary key column nullable?

Comment: @tadman I wanted to make the question more generic to have more chances to have answer, the models are obvious, three classes, two `belongs_to` and two `has_many`

Comment: @max maybe my hypothesis was wrong, I just know it was returning wrong results

Comment: Fair enough, but a lot of this does translate into ActiveRecord if you leverage the relationships you have in your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want *questions* without an answer:

```
select q.title
from questions q left join
     answers a
     on a.question_id = q.id and a.user_id = 1
where a.question_id is null;
```

Some notes:

- Aggregation is not needed.
- You are looking for non-matches.  Using a `LEFT JOIN`, just check if there are no non-matches.
- `FULL JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause is really somewhat complicated to explain.  But essentially you are getting all answers for `user_id = 1` along with questions for all other users.

Comment: why can't I put the `a.user_id = 1` in a `where`?

Comment: @Dorian . . . You *can* do that.  It just turns the outer join into an inner join, so the query would not do what you intend.